# How to split a string and get specific values

Tags: php, split, explode, substr

`$string = "706AN=0,503-PP=0,504-PP=0,519=0,606BOX=0,417=2";` **// This variable is a result from a database column type text**

I need to get individually the code before "=" and the result assigned to that code, after "=". The split string should return me something like:

```
Code 706AN has quantity 0  
Code 503-PP has quantity 0  
Code 504-PP has quantity 0  
Code 519 has quantity 0  
Code 606BOX has quantity 0  
Code 417 has quantity 2
```

How can I substract each code with his own quantity result?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Split on comma then split each values on equal sign. Then ask a question if it doesn't work.

Comment: $res = explode(',',$string);
foreach($res as $k => $v){
    $ex = explode("=",$v);
    echo "code:". $ex[0]. " has ".$ex[1];
}                                                                                                                                                          that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use explode

**Working Demo**: https://eval.in/869203

```
$string = "706AN=0,503-PP=0,504-PP=0,519=0,606BOX=0,417=2";
$temp = explode(',', $string);


foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
    list($code,$quantity) = explode('=', $value);
    echo "Code $code has quantity $quantity </br>";
}
```

Comment: Not sure why it did not echoed me all codes, but I addeed an array.

Comment: Actually, I did not had to echo the result of list, just to use those individual codes for other purposes.

Comment: then create an array to store those values: `$array[$code] = $quantity;` in foreach

Comment: Exactly that I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "706AN=0,503-PP=0,504-PP=0,519=0,606BOX=0,417=2";
$exp = explode(',', $string);

foreach ($exp as $key => $value) {
    $list = explode('=', $value);
    echo "Code $list[0] has quantity $list[1] </br>";
}
```

Comment: How is this different from @JigarShah 's answer?

Answer (score -1):

- 1) Split the String by the "," (comma)
- 2) loop over the resulting array
- 2.1)Split the String-part by "="
- 2.2) First part of the result is the name and the second is the quanitity
- 2.3) Create a new String ala "Code $name has quantity $qtty"
- 2.4) Add it to a list, a String or whatever datastructure you like

I can give you a code example later, im in a hurry atm

hth